# How to use random numbers as an input for a if statement?

Tags: python

I am making a small text based adventure game, I am trying to use the random feature built into python to generate a number. Based on the number it will allow you to continue or to die on the adventure.

N/A

```
import random
i = random.randint(1, 2)
if i == '1':
  print("hello")
if i == '2':
  print("Hi")
```

N/A

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Just remove the quotes:

```
import random
i = random.randint(1, 2)
if i == 1:
  print("hello")
if i == 2:
  print("Hi")
```

If you have quotes around the 1 and 2, i will be evaluated as a string but you've defined it as an integer.